# How to fix ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number DatabaseError

Tags: python, sql, sql-insert, cx-oracle

I am trying to write some rows of a `csv` file (or `pandas dataframe`) in my Oracle database using python (`cx_Oracle`).

I copy the rows of the dataframe/csv in a list `rows` which looks then as follows:

``

```
 [....,
 ['977', '980', '40', '152.9', '2011-08-22'],
 ['978', '981', '41', '155.5', '2011-08-22'],
 ['979', '982', '42', '149.3', '2011-08-22'],
 ['980', '983', '43', '153.5', '2011-08-22'],
 ['981', '984', '44', '149.5', '2011-08-22'], 
 ....]
```

``

The first element of the different rows is the primary key. The table in the database has the same structure. 
I try to copy the rows in the table as follows:

``

```
cursor.prepare('insert into REGULAR values (:1, :2, :3, :4)')
cursor.executemany(None, rows)
connection.commit()
```

``

As result I always get this error : 
`DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

Could someone help. Thank you!

PS.: I already found threads with questions related to this error, but this couldn't help since the situations are completely different.

Comment: Are there supposed to be 5 columns of data and only 4 columns in the `regular` table?

Comment: @JohnHC  The table contains 4 data. The first element in the list `rows` is the index.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is an index, it is still being used as input data so you have a mismatch between the 5 data values and the 4 bind variables.

Comment: @ChristopherJones it still gives an error even if I try with 5 bind variables. This time it is `DatabaseError: ORA-00913` which means `Too many values inserted`. Is there other problems?

Comment: How many columns does the `REGULAR` table have?  What are their types?  I expect you have only 4 columns and are still trying to insert 5 values. I suggest you start with some of the examples shown in https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle and see how `executemany()` works.